# System Boot Order not Found- after software update

Tags: boot-order

Ubuntu 18.04LTS won't boot after software update. System Boot Order not Found.
How do I restore the boot order?

Comment: https://www.experthoot.com/how-to-repair-ubuntu-if-it-wont-boot/ may be helpful

Comment: Good article. Thanks. Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

Astoundingly.. this issue was caused by a plugged-in USB headset. I don't yet know enough about Linux to determine how the hell something like a USB headset could affect the reading of a system boot order. I would sure like to know. Is this explainable?

Anyway.. if you have a boot order problem, try unplugging all your USB devices before you go deeper down the rabbit hole.